# ffmpeg missing image frames in generated video from images

Tags: image, video, windows-7, ffmpeg, codec

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8384142/2620328), but not yet answered.

#### Problem:

I'm combining images (.png) of same resolution/size (they all came from the same matplotlib.pyplot), but the resulting video is missing several frames.

#### Command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1 -i .\\images\\image%02d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 .\\images\\output.mp4
```

#### Resulting Video

- Length of 0:09
- Missing more than half the images

#### Images

- .\images

  - image00.png
  - image01.png
  - image02.png
  - image03.png
  - image04.png
  - image05.png
  - image06.png
  - image07.png
  - **. . .**

#### Notes:

I followed examples from [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images). I'm new to using ffmpeg, so I may not be completely sure of what each of the command line options I've used means, though I have a pretty good idea.

Thanks, any help/advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated. I am also perfectly willing to provide further information that may help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this happens if the images are not all exactly the same size. Your command looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! They are the same size. I made a silly mistake actually, which I am about to resolve by answering my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I saved my images as:

#### Images

```
.\images
    image00.png
    image01.png
    image02.png
    image03.png
    image04.png
    image05.png
    image06.png
    image08.png
    image09.png
    image010.png #<---- crap. all hells gone loose now.
    image011.png
    image012.png
    image013.png
    image014.png
    image015.png
```

Because I saved them in a for loop and tried to do some fancy name generating script that failed miserably. For reference though, this is the code that works:

```
for i in range(len(frames)):
    fig.savefig('images\\' + 'image'+ ('{0:0'+str(len(str(len(frames))))+'}').format(i)+'.png')
```

Comment: In the future to avoid padding issues, you can use string number formatting like %5d to create your filenames.

Comment: Something like print '%4d' % 10, gives me '  10' rather than '0010' though.

Comment: %02d would pad one. i forgot to mention that is a two parameter string format. use 0 instead of spaces to pad a field when the width option is specified. For example, printf("%2d", 3) results in " 3", while printf("%02d", 3) results in "03". so %04d would be 3 leading zeros